# How to stop waiting in XCTest when failureExecption is met

Tags: swift, xctest

In the TestCase, I call an async function aTestFunction(). In the callback, depends on the result, it decides whether it meets the expectation `expectation.fulfill()` or it failed
`failedExpectation.fulfill()`

Since it is an async function, I need to `wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5.0)` for the result. My question is 'When the test failed `failedExpectation.fulfill()`, i should not need to wait for 5 sec for 'expectation', how can I stop the 'wait' when `failedExpectation` is fulfilled"?

```
let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "succeed")
let failedExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "failed")
failedExpectation.isInverted = true
        
aTestFunction() { result in 
     if result == .success {
         expectation.fulfill()
     } else {
         failedExpectation.fulfill()
     }
 }
        
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create two `XCTestExpectation`:

```
let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Test function completion not called")
    
aTestFunction() { result in 
    expectation.fulfill()
    if result == .success {
        /// write successful test case here
    } else {
        XCTFail("Test function fails")
    }
 }
    
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5.0)
```

If `aTestFunction` not complete in 5 then the test case will fail.

if it is completing in 5 then expectation has been fulfilled and now you have to test if the expected result is there or not.